# Not able to copy ps1 files to nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, nuget, csproj-user

I have created a nuget package for a service. I need to add a few ps1 scripts inside this nuget package. I am trying to achieve the same using this:

```
<ItemGroup>    
<Content PackagePath="lib\net472\" Include="<packagepath>\net472\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In this, `<packagepath>\net472` has variety of files and folders. It has ps1 scripts, dlls, exe files etc. This above line is only copying the dlls and exe files but not the ps1 scripts. If I try to copy using `*.ps1` instead of `**` then I see error saying that it should be in tools folder. If I create a tools folder and put in it, it says the scripts should be named `install.ps1` or `uninstall.ps1` or `init.ps1` etc. But I have a bunch of ps1 files and I need to copy them as they are without changing the names.
Note: This works in non-SDK style of coding but mine is a csproj with SDK style. I am new to .NET, c sharp and this entire ecosystem. Can someone please help me how to resolve this?